# Where can I find a computational fluid dynamics model of a full quadcopter or multirotor?

Tags: multirotor, design

I have searched for any computerized graphics visualization of a quadcopter or other multirotor and all I am able to find are a very few models of a single propeller. (Simscale has an example of a single quad arm and rotor [here:](https://www.simscale.com/projects/Vadshe/drone/)) Has anyone seen a full multirotors visualizations produced by computational fluid dynamics (CFD)? NOTE: I am not looking for a schematic animation. Those are abundant.

Comment: I've not seen anything like that. I'm sure it exists in some limited fashion (DJI internal docs certainly, and maybe drone racing?), but multirotors are pretty uninteresting when it comes to flight dynamics. Basically, they ain't got none. They're literally the real-world manifestation of "you can make a barn door fly if you put on a big enough engine". They're comedically draggy and have odd regimes of flight. They're also indestructible, which is why we love them. But IMO from a scientific perspective their interest is for their motion dynamics, not in their aerodynamics. Hope you get lucky!

Comment: @KennSebesta I may need to make my own luck. I am looking at SimScale and there are a very limited number of studies of propellers. And a couple of studies of rotors on arms similar to how we typically see drones built today. So, it might turn out I may be the first to attempt it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own using free software.

Let’s take Fusion 360 as an example, in its simulation suite it has a Computational Fluid Dynamics study option.

If you’re willing to design an accurate-ish model of the aircraft you want, or pay someone to design one for you, you can run the CFD simulation and get the results for yourself.

This is obviously CPU intensive so there is an option to run it in the cloud on Autodesk’s servers.

Comment: Thanks @Drones-and-Whatnot I have used Fusion 360 in the past and just recently noticed that it has this feature, but I must be really bad at finding the free demo version of the CFD feature. I will return to it and give it my best effort.

Comment: All evidence I find is that a subscription is required to use the CFD feature of Fusion 360, It is not available in the free version. ~~ I am open to correction if anyone finds otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Thats definetely a late response but in case anyone is interested in the same topic, I found SimScale platform quite handy when trying to test a couple of CFD and FEA models.

With respect to drones, they provide this public (and free) [Quadcopter Drone CFD](https://www.simscale.com/projects/slaine/quadcopter_drone) simulation model.

If you are new to simulation, it might definetely be a good starting point.

Good luck!